# How to edit ExecutionContext spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, executioncontext

is there any way to add entry in the executioncontext other than read(), updated(), and open() method.

Like in the below code I'm trying to add entry in the close method.

```
public class MyFileReader extends FlatFileItemReader<AccountDetails>{
private long currentRowProcessedCount = 0;

    @Autowired
    private ExecutionContext executionContext;

    @Override
    public synchronized AccountDetails read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException {      
        AccountDetails accDetailsObj = super.read();

        currentRowProcessedCount++;

        return accDetailsObj;
    }   

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        super.open(executionContext);

        currentRowProcessedCount = executionContext.getLong(Constants.CONTEXT_COUNT_KEY.getStrValue(),0);
        this.executionContext = executionContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {  


        executionContext.putLong(Constants.CONTEXT_COUNT_KEY.getStrValue(), currentRowProcessedCount);
    }


    @Override
    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
        System.out.println("close --------------"+currentRowProcessedCount);
        System.out.println(executionContext.getLong(Constants.CONTEXT_COUNT_KEY.getStrValue()));
         this.executionContext.putLong(Constants.CONTEXT_COUNT_KEY.getStrValue(), currentRowProcessedCount);


    }
 }
```

in the above example I'm not able to updated new entry.
It' only working as readonly. I can read data but no write.

```
class abc{
@Autowired
private ExecutionContext executionContext;

    public AccountDetails mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {

                    executionContext.putLong(Constants.CONTEXT_COUNT_KEY.getStrValue(), 47);

        return accDetailsObj;
        }

}
```

I need to updated executionContext in other classes also.
Is there any way?

Comment: Can you share the configuration of your reader?

Answer (score 0):

You just use `put(String key, Object value)` to override already existing value.
ExecutionContext is backed by `ConcurrentHashMap` so if you really want it you can get reference to it via reflection and then use `computeIfAbsent`, etc...

Also counting already implemented in `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader` and If you inherited from it (and you are), this should be already solved.

Comment: already tries with put(,) in the other class. Please look into updated code.. I want to edit executioncontext in mapper class, where in current code I can only read the data. if I put data into execution context in my batch tables it's not getting reflected in the step execution context table

Comment: I don't understand. What is your goal? Do you want to propagate `ExecutionContext` to `StepContext`?

Comment: To retry job I want exact value/count where job got fail .. from that point I want to retry job.. In current case if job execution fails it stores chunk value not exact location where chunk failed